# How to use fluentd log driver on Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to use fluentd log driver with the following Dockerrun.aws.json,

```
    {
      "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
      "containerDefinitions": [
        {
          "name": "apache",
          "image": "php:5.6-apache",
          "essential": true,
          "memory": 128,
          "portMappings": [
            {
              "hostPort": 80,
              "containerPort": 80
            }
          ],
          "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "fluentd",
            "options": {
              "fluentd-address": "127.0.0.1:24224"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

but the following error occurred.

```
ERROR: Encountered error starting new ECS task: {cancel the command.
    "failures": [
        {
            "reason": "ATTRIBUTE",
            "arn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:000000000000:container-instance/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        }
    ],
    "tasks": []
}
ERROR: Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.
ERROR: [Instance: i-00000000] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: beanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/03start-task.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

What sould do I configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you can also accomplish it with `.ebextensions/01-fluentd.config` file in your application environment directory with the following content:

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/setup-available-log-dirvers.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      set -e
      if ! grep fluentd /etc/ecs/ecs.config &> /dev/null
      then
        echo 'ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS=["json-file","syslog","fluentd"]' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
      fi

container_commands:
  01-configure-fluentd:
    command: /home/ec2-user/setup-available-log-dirvers.sh
```

Now you have to deploy a new application version (without fluentd configuration yet), rebuild your environment, add fluentd configuration:

```
  logConfiguration:
    logDriver: fluentd
    options:
      fluentd-address: localhost:24224
      fluentd-tag: docker.myapp
```

and now deploy updated app, everything should work now.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will try it after a few days and report the result here.

Comment: I have confirmed that it works correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: Which solution stack is this with?  I've added the file to .ebextensions and verified that /etc/ecs/ecs.config is getting updated but the ecs agent is not running with the updated logging drivers.  I would guess that the ecs agent is starting up before that config is changed.

Comment: @matheeeny have you done environment rebuild (by going into beanstalk -> environment -> actions -> rebuild environment), after you have added .ebextensions file and deployed a version with that file?
I have used it with some previous version of `Multi-container Docker 1.9.1 (Generic)`.

Comment: I did not rebuild the environment but I did an immutable deployment which tears down the instances and launches new ones.

Comment: One problem that we were facing while setting this up was that elastic container task needed an restart and the ebextension script above was not doing that for me. After struggling little bit with it and some help from AWS we were able to pin point it. To resolve it we just need to restart ECS. And here is the script for that     `container_commands:
  00-configure-fluentd:
    command: /home/ec2-user/setup-available-log-dirvers.sh
  01-stop-ecs:
    command: stop ecs
  02-stop-ecs:
    command: start ecs
  03-start-fluentd:
    command: /etc/init.d/td-agent start`

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem myself.

First, I prepare a custom ami having the following user data.

```
#cloud-config
repo_releasever: 2015.09
repo_upgrade: none
runcmd:
  - echo 'ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS=["json-file","syslog","fluentd"]' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Second, I define the ami id which is created custom ami in my environment EC2 settings. Finally, I deploy my application to Elastic Beanstalk. After this, fluentd log driver in my environment works normally.

In order to use fluentd log driver in Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer Docker, it requires to define `ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS` variable in `/etc/ecs/ecs.config`. Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer Docker is using ECS inside, thus related settings is in the ECS documentation.
Please read `logConfiguration` section in the following documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

I have added a comment already to the accepted answer, just adding the complete ebextension file that I used to make it work for me

```
files:
"/home/ec2-user/setup-available-log-dirvers.sh":
mode: "000755"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  #!/bin/sh
  set -e
  if ! grep fluentd /etc/ecs/ecs.config &> /dev/null
  then
    echo 'ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS=["json-file","syslog","fluentd"]' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
  fi

container_commands:
 00-configure-fluentd:
  command: /home/ec2-user/setup-available-log-dirvers.sh
 01-stop-ecs:
  command: stop ecs
 02-stop-ecs:
  command: start ecs
```

We are just restating ecs after setting logging drivers